# How i can retrieve specific column in Hyperlink using ado.net

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, ado.net

I am making a website of tutorials So i want to retrieve Subjects name in hyperlink from a database and show the content of the subject on a web page.So how i can use ado.net to Retrieve Subject Name in hyperlink and Subject Content on a webpage???

[image]

Comment: Are you using a GridView to display Hyperlinks (for Subject name) ?

Comment: No i am using Hyperlink is a Vertical menu of links to retrieve subject When someone click on subject it goes on that subject

Answer (score 0):

i think you have use

```
<%=dt.rows[i]["subjectname"].tostring()%>
```

it is use in aspx page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when i use your logic it gave me an error that there is no row it 1 position.Give me complete solution.

Comment: please check datatable is empty the use

Comment: Datatable is not empty.

Comment: Can you please give your fb account to send you whole idea then you can understand better and answer better